# Run ASP on Apache / Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hosting, asp

Now I know this is quite a tricky one, but so many different sites say different things about doing this so I'm looking for a comprehensive answer here;

I'm currently in charge of moving about 450 clients over to a new hosting platform, and unfortunately around 50 of them are using ASP.

Rather than set up a separate Windows server just to accommodate this 50 people for a short while until we expand, it would be great if I could get these running on a separate Linux machine.

Is there a good guide out there anywhere, or has anyone got any advice? I know it's not the best option, but it's only a temporary measure.

Comment: I assume if they're clients, they're paying you? In that case I feel you owe it to them to set up a Windows server and do it properly.

Comment: I see what your saying, but the period will only be a couple of days (when our new Windows dedi's will be available) so I'm just looking for a very short term solution.

Comment: Move them after your windows dedicated boxes are ready, for a 'few days' I wouldn't deploy on to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon EC2 has Windows machines: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/